# using recursive CTE within a function

Tags: postgresql, function, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I wanted to try out using a recursive CTE for the first time, so I wrote a query to show the notes in a musical scale based on the root note and the steps given the different scales.

When running the script itself all is well, but the second that I try to make it into a function, I get the error "relation "temp_scale_steps" does not exist".

I am using postgreSQL 9.4.1.  I can't see any reason why this would not work.  Any advice would be gratefully received.

The code below:

```
create or replace function scale_notes(note_id int, scale_id int)
returns table(ordinal int, note varchar(2)) 
as
$BODY$

drop table if exists temp_min_note_seq;
create temp table temp_min_note_seq
as
select min(note_seq_id) as min_note_id from note_seq where note_id = $1
;

drop table if exists temp_scale_steps;
create temp table temp_scale_steps
as
with recursive steps (ordinal, step) as 
(
select  ordinal
        ,step 
from scale_steps 
where scale_id = $2
    union all
select  ordinal+1
    ,step 
from steps
where ordinal < (select max(ordinal) from scale_steps where scale_id = $2)
)
select  ordinal 
        ,sum(step) as temp_note_seq_id 
from steps
group by 1
order by 1
;

select  x.ordinal
        ,n.note
from 
(
    select  ordinal
            ,min_note_id + temp_note_seq_id as temp_note_seq_id
    from temp_scale_steps
    join temp_min_note_seq on (1=1)
) x
join note_seq ns on (x.temp_note_seq_id = ns.note_seq_id)
join notes n on (ns.note_id = n.note_id)
order by ordinal;

$BODY$
language sql volatile;
```

In response to comments I have changed the script so that the query is done in one step and now all works.  However, I would still be interested to know why the version above does not work.

Comment: Why are you creating a temp table at all? That's totally unnecessary. You can do it in a single query. Something like: http://pastebin.com/BuUSvcAX (although I think this can be further simplified)

Comment: thanks, I saw your comment and came up with something similar.  Still not sure why it can't find the table though in the original version.

Comment: The table isn't there before you actually run the function. But the body of the function is validated when you create the function and at that time the table is indeed not there and hence the error.